# Swift - macOS Program Stuck when Saving Dictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

I have been trying to save a Dictionary of type [Int:String] into NSUserDefaults, which used to work well, but lately just won't. The macOS program gets stuck (with the rainbow loader) when the saving method is called and never recovers.

Since I was able to do this before, I am suspecting this might have something to do with the location where NSUserDefaults get stored on my mac (I don't know where that is).

Here is my code:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var dict: [Int: String] = [:]
    dict[1] = "123512"
    dict[2] = "1231232"
    dict[3] = "112512"
    dict[4] = "1212081"
    print(dict)
    defaults.setObject(dict, forKey: "cameraOrder")
```

Currently, objectForKey: "cameraOrder" is empty, which I did by calling "defaults delete [Bundle ID]" on the terminal.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I think that might problem might have something to do with the saving of a dictionary type. If I run this code:

```
    defaults.setObject("12", forKey: "cameraOrder")
    print(defaults.objectForKey("cameraOrder"))
```

It works perfectly.

Surprisingly, even if I save a dictionary of type [String:String] it works (Changing the key 1 to "1")

Comment: how you fetch youre dictionary from NSUserDefaults

Comment: defaults.objectForKey("cameraOrder"), but my problem is not with fetching, since just saving makes the program eternally stuck.

Comment: @EricAya could you please take a look at answer if it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fetch properly dictionary from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let dictionaryForUserDefaults = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("cameraOrder") as? [Int: String] {

}
```

Today i investigate this issue. Try to test with real Xcode not with playground.

When you run you're code in the Xcode you will receive.

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
>       2 = 123512;
>       3 = 123512;
>       1 = 123512;
>       4 = 123512; } as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key cameraOrder

It is possible to conclude that Dictionary is not `non-property-list object`. And lets read carefully from apple docs:

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to
>   be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the
>   collections are not property-list objects.

So keys in you're case are Int and there is a problem.

For solving of the issue try :

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let key = "cameraOrder"

var dict: [String: String] = [:]
dict["1"] = "123512"
dict["2"] = "1231232"
dict["3"] = "112512"
dict["4"] = "1212081"

print(dict)

defaults.setObject(dict, forKey: key)
```

Comment: I tried fetching (both as an object and dictionary), but it returns nil. The problem is with saving without question.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, this is exactly what I ended up doing, but your well-documented answer helps a lot. Please also consider upvoting my question if you find that it can be helpful for others in the future.